Dying man's wish is to have sex with his friends' girlfriends
This was likely made in the last 5 years. Comedy-ish. I have only seen the trailer. I believe it concerns a dying man, maybe cancer, who invites a few friends and their girlfriends to cabin so that he can ask them if he can sleep with their girlfriends before he dies.
The film is in English and I am almost positive it is an American film. None of the actors are particularly well known. The setting is the present day. Likely an independent movie. Not 50/50. 

Please provide as many details as possible: Country\language, specific scenes, possible actors, films you've ruled out etc. ID questions without sufficient details are likely to be closed.

Sounds like The Big Ask from 2013, but the guy isn't dying.

Three couples head to the desert to help their friend heal after the death of his mother. They would do anything for him - except for the one thing he wants.

That one thing is to sleep with all their girlfriends. I can understand your confusion, though, because the phrase 'dying of cancer' appears at least twice in the trailer (it's his mom who died of cancer). Here's the trailer:




Wow thats the one! Thank you so much. I didn't have many details to give and I got most of those wrong but you found it anyway. I can't believe I didn't remember that Gillian Jacobs was in this.
