# Man's 'last wish' before dying is to sleep with best friend's wife

Tags: identify-this-movie

A man was diagnosed with a heart condition and needed surgery. Of course, he had a very low chance to survive. So he returned to his town and told the father of the small town that his last wish was to have sex with his best friend's wife. By the way, she was the hottest woman in the town. (She was of east European origin, Slovenian I think.) The wife didn't seem to be upset at all with the idea and of course the husband was very concerned about it.

At the end, they had sex and the dying man went to have his operation. A couple of months pass, the hot wife was pregnant, with the chance that the child could be from the dying man. He was still alive and returned to the town.

That's all I can remember.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dying man's wish is to have sex with his friends' girlfriends](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37056/dying-mans-wish-is-to-have-sex-with-his-friends-girlfriends)

Comment: Thank you men, but no it's not a duplicate. It has a different plot completely

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an Italian film "L'Amico del cuore (The friend of the heart)". It is a 1998 film written and directed by Vincenzo Salemme.

The protagonist Roberto Cordova (Vincenzo Salemme) must undergo a heart operation. Very risky, so that Roberto thinks of dying. Thinking that decides to take all the whims that has always had. One of them is sleeping with the wife of his best friend, Michele Seta. Initially it only revealed to Leonardo's father.

Leonardo's father does not want to reveal Michele his last wish because otherwise everyone will think that you have the same right. Nevertheless Roberto goes to Michele and tells him to do so and his last wish. Michele, at first, thought to be a joke, but then you realize the seriousness of his friend 's wife.

In the film of Michele's wife is Frida (Eva Herzigová) known Czech model.

Today the script has become a comedy for theatre.